# Solving a nonlinear first order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

In this text https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461454762 on p. 95, it has the following

[image]

The text does not explain how to get to this solution. $B, C, D$ are arbitrary constants. With $A>0$, I came to something like this $$Y_0=B\tan\left(\frac{B\bar{x}}{2}+C\right)$$ Is that and the positive case solution the same? Also how did the negative case solution come about?

Comment: We have $2\int\frac{dY_0}{Y_0^2+2A}=x$ and the LHS is a standard integral. The sign of $A$ evidently matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this like a Riccati equation and set $Y=-2\frac{u'}{u}$ so that
$$
Y'=-2\frac{u''}{u}+2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}+A\iff u''+\frac{A}2u=0
$$
This now is a standard linear DE with constant coefficients and you can easily treat the 3 cases $A=2B^2$, $A=-2B^2$ and $A=0$.

\begin{align}
u''+B^2u&=0\implies& u&=\cos(Bx+C),&~~Y&=2B\tan(Bx+C)\\
u''&=0&\implies u&=Dx+C,&~~Y&=-\frac{2D}{Dx+C}\\
u''-B^2u&=0\implies & u&=Ce^{Bx}+De^{-Bx},&~~ Y&= -2B\frac{Ce^{Bx}-De^{-Bx}}{Ce^{Bx}+De^{-Bx}}
\end{align}

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you explain a bit more as to the transformation between $Y$ and $u$? How did the $A$ come in the $-2\frac{u''}{u}+2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=2\frac{u'^2}{u^2}+A$?

Comment: It is the right side, $\frac12Y^2+A=...$. The coefficient of $\frac{u'}{u}$ is chosen so that the quadratic term cancels against the second part of the quotient rule.